# Getting data from GridView on Button_Click

Tags: asp.net, gridview, postback, buttonclick, dataitem

My problem is:

I have a GridView, which is bound to list of declared DTO objects with column of CheckBoxes. Also, I have a "Save" button on the page. My mission concludes in getting all rows, where CheckBox is checked and get the containing data. Unfortunately, row.DataItem = null on Button1_Click, because, I'm using if(!IsPostBack) gw.DataBind() statement (otherwise, I can't get CheckBox status). Could you give me the best practice for solving my problem?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do `if(!IsPostBack) --> gw.DataBind()`, that will reinitialize your `GridView` and the checkboxes will be set to unchecked again.

In your case, in `Button1_Click` event, you can loop through each `DataRow` on your `GridView` and find the row which has it's checkbox checked and get all the selected row data.

```
foreach (GridViewRow gvRow in gw.Rows) {
// Find your checkbox
    CheckBox chkBox = (CheckBox)gvRow.FindControl("checkBox");

    if (chkBox.Checked) {
    // Get your values 
        string value1 = gvRow.Cells[1].Text;
        string value2 = gvRow.Cells[2].Text;
        // etc...
    }
}
```

Comment: That's why I'm stuck. If I DataBind every time page loads, I can't get CheckBox values. If I use !IsPostBack -> row.DataItem == null ,so I can't get row's data.

Comment: Please, explain, how I'm supposed to get all the row data?

Comment: gvRow.Cells[1].ToString() gives me    "System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlFieldCell", not the containing value.

Comment: I tried to use foreach(var row in GridView.Rows) var myObject=row.DataItem; But DataItem = null

Comment: It should be gvRow.Cells[1].Text, sorry abt that

Comment: Hmm, it works, but only if there are no controls in the cell. I know, I can use FindControl() in that case, but is access to cells the best practice of getting data from GridView rows? Thank you for your effort!

Comment: I have used the method that I explained without any problem and other sources also recommend the same solution. Other way I can think of is by storing keys from each of checked rows and searching them back in datasource. However, this involves more work. Please share if you find any other practice so that I can learn :). Thanks!